# Spring ordered list of beans

Tags: java, spring, sorting, spring-mvc, ioc-container

I have several beans that implement the same interface.
Each bean is annotated with

```
@Component 
@Order(SORT_ORDER).
public class MyClass implements BeanInterface{
    ...
}
```

At one point I autowire a list of components and I expect a sorted list of beans. 
The list of beans is not sorted according the orders I have set with the annotation.

I tried implementing the interface Ordered and the same behaviour occurs.

```
@Component
public class Factory{


    @Autowired
    private List<BeanInterface> list; // <- I expect a sorted list here
    ...
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found a solution to the issue, as you say, this annotation is not meant for that despite it would be a nice feature.

To make it work this way its just necessary to add the following code in the bean containing the sorted list.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    Collections.sort(list,AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.INSTANCE);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is this still the case with Spring 4?

Answer (score 40):

Ordering autowired collections is supported since Spring 4.

See: [Spring 4 Ordering Autowired Collections](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/spring-4-ordering-autowired-collections/)

Summary: if you add `@Order(value=1)`, `@Order(value=2)`... to your bean definitions, they will be injected in a collection ordered according to the `value` parameter. This is not the same as declaring that you want the collection in *natural order* - for that you have to explicitly sort the list yourself after receiving it, as per [Jordi P.S.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16981258/587365).

Comment: this is useful for many people but doesn't answer the actual question.  Also it's best to put the info in the answer itself in case the blog disappears. I edited to add a summary.

Comment: Link to the [official Spring 5 docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.19/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-ordered).

Answer (score 1):

For Spring versions < 4, the `@Order` annotation is used to specify the order in which AOP advice is executed, it doesn't sort lists.  To achieve sorting on your list have your `BeanInterface` classes implement the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Comparable.html) interface and override the `compareTo` method to specify how the objects should be sorted. Then you can sort the list using `Collections.sort(list)`.  Assuming `BeanInterface` has a method called `getSortOrder` that returns an `Integer` object specifying the object's sort order, you could do something like this:

```
@Component 
public class MyClass implements BeanInterface, Comparable<BeanInterface> {
    public Integer getSortOrder() {
        return sortOrder;
    }

    public int compareTo(BeanInterface other) {
        return getSortOrder().compareTo(other.getSortOrder());
    }
}
```

Then you can sort the list like this:

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

Comment: This answer seems valid only for spring < 4

Comment: @tkruse I guess that makes sense since the answer was posted in June of 2013, long before Spring 4 existed.

Comment: Just scope it like "For Spring Versions before 4" or so to fix.

Answer (score 1):

There is a jira issue about that feature in spring. I have added an implementation of beanfactory in the comment which im currently using to support that feature:

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5574

Answer (score 0):

`@Order` annotation is here for rescue.

I am using **SpringBoot 2.6.1** and its a working code snippet for me without adding any `@PostConstruct` to apply the sorting explicitely.

```
interface MyFilter {
  
}
```

Below are multiple implementations for the interface

```
@Order(value=1)
public class MyFilterImpl1 implements MyFilter {
} 


@Order(value=2)
public class MyFilterImpl2 implements MyFilter {
} 


@Order(value=3)
public class MyFilterImpl3 implements MyFilter {
}
```

And below is the class where the list of MyFilter implementation needs to be injected.

```
@Component
    @RequiredArgConstructor
    public class MyBean {
     private final List<MyFilter> myFilters;
    }
```