# How (and when) to initialize a Spring bean which needs to access other beans only known in runtime?

Tags: java, spring, initialization, postconstruct

I have a Spring webapp running on Java 5. This <strike>is</strike> *was* my applicationContext.xml file:

```xml
<bean id="child1" class="foo.ChildOne" />
<bean id="child2" class="foo.ChildTwo" />
<bean id="main" class="foo.Main">
  <property name="childrenList">
    <list value-type="foo.IChildren">
      <ref bean="child1" />
      <ref bean="child2" />
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Both `ChildOne` and `ChildTwo` classes implement the `IChildren` interface. And in my `Main` class, I have defined a `childrenList` which gets populated with `child1` and `child2` beans. [Easy, right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416056/how-to-define-a-list-bean-in-spring)

But in the future, there might be no `child1`, and instead, we will maybe have a `child81` based on another unknown class. And it still has to work without touching the current code or XML files, only through configuration. This `child81` would be defined on its own applicationContext file (in a JAR), and we will list the bean names in a database field (`child2,child81,etc`).

<sup>*I guess that's not a good design pattern; most likely it's a terrible, horrible, painful, you-better-run-while-you-can design, which will haunt me in the years to come. But I didn't define it, and **I can't change it**, so please lets assume it's OK for the purpose of this question.*</sup>

Instead of injecting the beans myself using the applicationContext.xml, I have to retrieve them somehow, in runtime. I can't use autowiring either, because I don't know what class the beans are, all I know is all of their classes implement `IChildren`.

So I have made my main bean class `ApplicationContextAware` and I have added this method:

```java
public void loadChildren() {
  if (childrenList == null) {
    childrenList = new LinkedList<IChildren>();
    for (String name : theListOfBeanNames) {
      childrenList.add((IChildren) context.getBean(name));
    }
  }
}
```

It works alright; each bean is defined in its own applicationContext, and then I retrieve them by name. But... when do I call `loadChildren()`? So far, I'm doing it in the first line of each one of my methods. Since there is a null-check, it will initialize the list only once. But surely, there must be an easier/cleaner/better way of doing this?

I don't think I can just **use the `init-method="loadChildren"` property** in my applicationContext, because then it would fail if my main bean is being loaded before all the children have been... and I can't control the loading order. Or can I?

This is from my web.xml file:

```xml
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/application-context/applicationContext-*.xml
    ,classpath*:WEB-INF/application-context/applicationContext-children.xml
  </param-value>
</context-param>
```

(We use the "[classpath* notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6451465/112934)" to load *every* applicationContext-children.xml file from within the JARs). If I invert the order and place the children XML before the main ones, would it ensure they will be loaded in that specific order? No matter what version of what application server we use?

I've also seen a [**`@PostConstruct` annotation**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16967971/spring-ordered-list-of-beans) which would be useful if I could add it to my `loadChildren` method. But when would it be called then? I've read that it's after the injections have been done, but... only for the current bean, right? It doesn't ensure that all the other beans are already loaded?

Is there any other option?

Comment: Just auto wire a list of the type `IChildren`... `@Autowired List<IChildren> childrenList` Spring will inject all available instances into the list. Or just inject de `ApplicationContext` as you do now and use `context.getBeansOfType(IChildren.class)` ... Also all the xml files are loaded at once, so when your `loadChildren` all the beans should be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring can do this for you:

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {
    @Autowired
    private final List<IChildren> children;

    ...
}
```

That will autowire in everything than implements `IChildren`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the children order in the list *does* matter... which is another reason why I can't use autowiring. However, this answers what I asked, so I'm marking it as accepted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

[Mr Spoon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48149901/112934) does exactly what I asked, so I'm marking it as the correct answer. However, I forgot to mention that the children order in the list *does* matter, so I still can't use autowiring. Here is what I ended up doing instead, in case anybody else finds it useful.

As stated in the answers [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409605/calling-a-method-after-all-springbeans-and-applicationcontext-have-been-initiali), another option is to catch the `ContextRefreshedEvent` by implementing the `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` interface. That ensures that the `loadChildren` method is executed only after all the initialization is done.

Since we are using a very old Spring version (2.0.7), our [`ApplicationListener` interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html) is slightly different, for example it doesn't support generic types. So, instead of [doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40978343/112934), my class looks like this:

```
public class Main implements ApplicationListener {

  public void loadChildren(ApplicationContext context) {
    //...
  }

  public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent ev) {
    if (ev instanceof ContextRefreshedEvent) {
      loadChildren(((ContextRefreshedEvent) ev).getApplicationContext());
    }
  }

}
```