# How can I test an old Spring 2.0.7 application with JUnit?

Tags: java, spring, junit4, spring2.x

I have an old app built with an ancient version of Spring: 2.0.7. I have been tasked with adding new functionality to this app, so I'm required to write some JUnit tests too.

So far, I have writen mockup classes for my services, and an `applicationContext-test.xml` file placed under `src/test/resources/`. Typically, the next step would be to write my test case like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/applicationContext-test.xml"})
public class MyTestCase {
    ...
}
```

But as I read, [the Spring TestContext Framework was first introduced](https://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles) in Spring 2.5, and therefore it's not available to me.

Is there any other way in which I can load the applicationContext.xml file within JUnit, and access the beans defined in that XML file?

Since I already have the mockups and they don't require initialization parameters, I could just instantiate them and pass them to the setter, maybe using the `@BeforeClass` annotation. But I would prefer using the Spring context, if possible, given that I ended up with a [somehow unusual way to load the beans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48165963/112934) and it should be tested too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended writing an ApplicationContext wrapper, and calling the `init` method myself with a `@Before` annotation, instead of relying on Spring to do that. This way, I can test my initialization method *as if it was called from Spring*.

```
public class ApplicationContextMock implements ApplicationContext {
    private Map<String, Object> beans;

    public ApplicationContextMock() {
        beans = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        beans.put("child1", new SomeServiceMock());
        beans.put("child2", new AnotherServiceMock());
    }

    public Object getBean(String arg0) throws BeansException {
        return beans.get(arg0);
    }
    // ...
}
```

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class MyTestCase {
    MyClass foo;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        foo = new MyClass();
        foo.loadChildren(new ApplicationContextMock());
    }

    // ...
}
```

(I still want to know if there is a better way of doing this, without the Spring 2.5+ annotations).